# What would be a good regular expression to match out indexes from a string variable?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string declared as:

```
String testString = "1: 2, 3\n2: 3, 4\n3: 1\n4: 2\n5: 6, 7, 8"
```

I want to write a regular expression which can return me the indexes, i.e., which returns me the following list(or any collection):

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I know if I write my regular expression as:

```
regex = r'[0-9]:'
```

I will get:

```
[1:,2:,3:,4:,5:]
```

However, this is not the desired output. I've just started with regular expressions, and I've applied all I know (so far) to this problem, however, I'm unable to write a valid regular expression. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using python? The tag says so, but your first code sample doesn't look so much like python. If you are, you can use your regex and then strip off the ':' characters with `s.strip(':')`

Comment: Thanks, and I'm sorry the first snippet looks a bit Java-ish. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `r'[0-9]+(?=:)'`, which uses a lookahead

Answer (score 1):

```
regx = re.compile('(?<!\d)\d+(?=\s*:)')
```

Comment: I wonder why I put ``(?<!\d)`` as a loobehind assertion, it's useless

Answer (score 1):

You could use your regex, then use a list comprehension to remove the trailing colons:

```
>>> [a.strip(':') for a in re.findall(r"[0-9]:", testString)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```